# Filling Text in a Cell based on Data in another Cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a Data like

```
G5MPMS4581X681GG03216AB7869HK
G5MPMS57269X791GG06814JA8917HK
```

And many more like these

Is it possible to split this into cells like the below

```
G5MPMS4581X681GG03216AB7869HK G5MPMS 4581 681 GG 03 2 1 6 AB7869 HK
G5MPMS57269X791GG06814JA8917HK G5MPMS 57269 681 GG 06 8 1 4 JA7869 HK
```

I tried with IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(
But only definite values were able to do.

Comment: What is logic to split text to those cells.

Comment: The logic would be what ever number falls between G5MPMS and X is to be splitted and Whatever in between X and next alphabet is to be splitted

Comment: From your output it seems you are splitting numbers into 2 digits, 1 digits.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your splitting logic. Your examples don't match what you write.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEFT` and `MID` and `FIND` functions to accomplish this task. I don't know your exact specs, but this should get you started.

If your data is in `A1` enter these formulas starting in `B1`:

`=LEFT($A1,6)` Returns G5MPMS for both cases

`=MID($A1,7, FIND("X",$A1,6)-7)` Returns 4581 for case 1, and 57269 for case 2

`=MID($A1,FIND("X",$A1,6)+1,3)` Returns 681 for case 1, and 791 for case 2

Continue using `MID` to return future data if fixed length, if not you will need to used find again.